# Execute php from joomla component on every page

Tags: php, joomla

I am learning how to write components in `joomla-3.x` (currently I'm using 3.6.5) and I'm having difficulties figuring out how to execute my own PHP code on *every* page. Is that even possible? If so how can it be achieved?

So far, I have been unable to add anything globally to all pages unless I modify joomla's own `index.php` and I'd rather not edit files outside the scope of my component.

Answer (score 0):

Executing code on every page is probably best done using a [plugin](https://docs.joomla.org/Category:Plugin_Development) or possibly a [module](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module).

An advantage of using a module is that you can use menu assignment to select which pages the code should be enabled on.